# Creating a 3-Questions Survey with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple survey of three questions that can be answered by clicking on a YES or NO HTML-Button. **The input/answers have to be stored until the third question is answered.** If all question are answered with YES, the output will be different from the output if a question is answered by NO.

Here is an example for a better understanding:

- Question 1: Do you like Bananas? Yes / No
- Question 2: Do you like Apples? Yes / No
- Question 3: Do you like Pineapple? Yes / No

If all three question are answered by YES the output would be: You like fruits!

If a question (or two, or all three of them) is answered with NO the output would be: You prefer candy!

Do I need PHP for this or is it possible to do this with Javascript? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can do this purely with JS, though you can also do it with PHP. It's so simple that pretty much any web language can do it.

Comment: @Sveninho Have a try first and then post a link here to what you have done - use jsfiddle.net or codepen.io or jsbin.com to try out your javascript and HTML (whichever of those sites seems easiest to you). You can do it entirely in javascript, no need for php to do what you have suggested.  Start here http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/ for a beginners tutorial, then look at the javascript tutorial.

Comment: @DanEastwell Thank you. I will. Since I am not very familiar with Javascript it will take some time I guess ...

Comment: @DanEastwell Hello Dan. I think i could manage it to store the value of the clicked button. Not sure if I'm on the right track ... here's my fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Sveninho/czactrg1/ according to my browser console, the data is saved in the varialbel/array. My next stept would be to write a statement ...

Comment: @Sveninho nice work :) Firstly, it looks like you're using jquery, but the saved fiddle doesn't have it included. Once that's sorted, try adding `<p id="answer"></p>` and then `$('#answer').text(answer.join())` that will output your answer to the DOM. You probably also need to add labels for your questions. You probably want to output a different answer depending on `answer.length`, too. I'd use `input type="radio"` instead of buttons, but that's something to work on once it's functional

Comment: @DanEastwell yes I am using JQuery. It's easier for me to understand. Thanks for the input. I will add it to my code. I let you know when I'm done with my next step.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript only, but a more important question is **how do you want to persist this information?** If you want to store this data permanently, then you would need some sort of server (using php or another framework). But if you don't need to persist this data, then javascript alone can do the trick.

Comment: It doesnt have to be stored permanently. I was considering using HTML5 sessionStorage Object for it. Only stored until tab is closed.

Comment: That would work. But to be honest, it seems a little overkill for just a 3-question survey. You could just store the selected values within a javascript array. They would persist until the tab is closed.